# how to make field inputable based on condition in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, python-2.x

I am setting up registration form where do i need to get Field A value's Into Field B based on selection choice.

```
field_a = fields.Char("Field A")
field_b = fields.Char("Field B", compute="mymethod")
field_selection = fields.Selection([('choice_a', "Choice A"), ('choice_b', "Choice B")]) 


@api.one 
@api.depends('selection_choice')
def mymethod(self):
    for res in self:
        if res.selection_choice == 'choice_a':
            res.field_b = res.field_a
        else:
            res.field_b = ""
```

But still showing in readonly field, how can make it inputable?

Comment: Is `selection_choice` a typo? Cause you have field `field_selection`, not `selection_choice`.

Answer (score 1):

`compute` field in odoo is by default `readonly=True` and `store=False`. You can set `store=True` by just passing that to the field definition, but to make the `compute` field inputable/not readonly, you have to pass `inverse` in the field definition, which is a string value, name of the function that is to run when a compute field value is set manually. The idea is, compute value `depends` on the field mentioned in `@api.depends` decorator. So if you set the `compute` field value using manually input, then you may need a `inverse` function which will set the corresponding `depends` field accordingly.

```
field_a = fields.Char("Field A")
field_b = fields.Char("Field B", compute="_compute_field_b", inverse="_set_field_b")
field_selection = fields.Selection([('choice_a', "Choice A"), ('choice_b', "Choice B")]) 

@api.multi 
@api.depends('field_selection, field_a')
def _compute_field_b(self):
    for res in self:
        if res.selection_choice == 'choice_a':
            res.field_b = res.field_a
        else:
            res.field_b = ""

@api.multi
def _set_field_b(self):
    for res in self:
         if res.field_selection == 'choice_a':
            res.field_a = res.field_b
```

If you don't need any `inverse` functionality on setting the revert value, you can just `return True` not doing anything else. This will make the compute field editable.